# php mail function doesn't work

Tags: php

```
$to= 'somebody@somedomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I am using this code try to send an email. But I have waited 10 minutes already and haven't received any email. What am I missing here?

Comment: external hosting? if so, does it allow to send emails from php? do you need to use an email address of your own domain as from address?

Comment: you better hide that email in your code before it makes into spam lists :)

Comment: **Too localized**. We can't guess your server configuration, and Stackoverflow has already enough poking-in-the-dark questions regarding the mail() function.

Comment: What @mario is getting at is that there isn't anything wrong with your code.  The issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee that emails will be delivered within any time frame. And if it is delivered, it could be in a spam box. Fortunately the mail() function return value indicates whether or not the mail was accepted by the sending mail server. If it's not accepted, you can be sure that it will not be delivered. All you need to do is check the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing's wrong in your code: I reproduced it and received the email.

Maybe it was sent to the junk box, maybe the message didn't even reach because the IP of the mail server was banned.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `IIS` server and sometimes it does not support sending mail using `PHP` and gives an error.

To overcome this problem you may use the below code in that PHP page which will use to send your mail:

```
<?php ini_set("sendmail_form", "info@mydomain.com"); ?>
```

Put the code in the first line of this page and then write other codes. Try it.

I guess your mail will be sent from this page to your senders.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting company probably doesn't have the mail() function enabled, or you didn't check your 'junk' folder in your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look to http://ch.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php page :

> For the Mail functions to be available, **PHP must have access to the
>   sendmail binary** on your system during compile time. If you use another
>   mail program, such as qmail or postfix, be sure to use the appropriate
>   sendmail wrappers that come with them. PHP will first look for
>   sendmail in your PATH, and then in the following:
>   /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc:/usr/ucblib:/usr/lib. It's highly
>   recommended to have sendmail available from your PATH. Also, the user
>   that compiled PHP must have permission to access the sendmail binary.